# Float Formatting

Tags: c#

I will need to format a float value to string as given below

```
1.0E11 -- 1.0E11  
1.21 -- 1.21
```

When tried with `ToString("0.00")` I got the following values:

```
1.0E11- "10000000000.00"  
1.21 - 1.21
```

How can we convert the float value to string with exponential value, if it has exponential?

Answer (score 3):

```
String.Format("{0:E4}", myFloat);
```

or

```
myFloat.ToString("E4"); // Where 4 is the number of decimal places
```

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx

Comment: But this also forces `1.21f` into an exponential form with `E+000`, and this is not what the asker wants, I think.

Comment: The format string I suggest in my answer, gives `"1.23"` for `1.2345f`, and `"1.23E+11"` for `1.2345e11f`, so it comes close to what (I think) the Original Poster wants.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen yes your answer comes closer than mine. I gave you +1

Answer (score 1):

I think `.ToString("G3")` comes close to what you want, but you don't specify how you want intermediate numbers, like `666.123f`, to be formatted.